# Having null response for a list inside a class object in REST API call with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, api, resttemplate, jsonschema2pojo

So I'm working on a REST client that consumes a REST API to get a JSON object using the Spring RestTemplate. So I get an HTTP 200 OK response but the list (equipment) inside the class object is null. But other fields are fetched. When I do the same request using the Postman it works well. What might be the reason for this?

The RestTemplate code snippet :

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    requestHeaders.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken);
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(requestHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<CloverMerchant> response = restTemplate.exchange(getMerchantDetailsUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, CloverMerchant.class);
    return response.getBody();
```

The CloverMerchant model class :

```
private String id;
private String name;
private String website;
private boolean isBillable;
private CloverBusinessEquipments equipment;

// other relevant getters and setters
```

The CloverBusinessEquipments model class:

```
private List<CloverBusinessEquipment> elements;

// relevant getters and setters
```

The CloverBusinessEquipment model class :

```
private String merchantId;
private String serialNumber;
private String equipmentCode;
private String equipmentCodeDesc;
private String provisionedDeviceType;
private boolean boarded;
private boolean provisioned;

// relevant getters and setters
```

The response JSON from the REST API:

```
{
  "id": "5ZTFCGXQKVZNA",
  "name": "xxxx",
  "website": "https://xxxx.io",
  "isBillable": false,
  "equipment": {
    "elements": [
        {
            "merchantId": "5ZTFCGXQKVZNA",
            "boarded": false,
            "provisioned": true,
            "serialNumber": "C030UQ71040182",
            "equipmentCode": "105J",
            "equipmentCodeDesc": "Clover Mini",
            "provisionedDeviceType": "MAPLECUTTER"
        },
        {
            "merchantId": "5ZTFCGXQKVZNA",
            "boarded": false,
            "provisioned": true,
            "serialNumber": "C050UQ75150054",
            "equipmentCode": "1297",
            "equipmentCodeDesc": "Clover Station 2018",
            "provisionedDeviceType": "GOLDENOAK"
        }
     ]
   }
}
```